# What is the difference between “比照” and “比较”？

Tags: usage, difference

I started learning Chinese not too long ago but have come across these expressions (比照 and 比较) when comparing things. I am confused as to whether I'm using it correctly. Would anyone be able to help tell me what situations to use which term?

Comment: see dictionaries, e.g. iciba,  比照: according to; in the light of; （对比） contrast, for 比较 which is much more common might again consult dictionaries, there find lots of examples showing in what situations they are used, jukuu also recommended

Answer (score 1):

In oral, we all say "比较". 比照 is seldom used in oral. They are almost equal. You'd better learn sentences first. Examples:
通过比较/比照，旧手机更好用。

那款手机比较漂亮。You can't use 比照 here. Here, 比较 means more or pretty.

Answer (score 1):

比較 has the meaning of comparing and coming to a conclusion of one's liking, 
我比較喜歡這款式，我比較不喜歡吃中餐 
whilst 
比照 (對比按照, in a comparative way) is used for following the same routines as in 這件事請比照辦理。 比照這方法去做。 比照平日處理。

Answer (score 1):

比 is short for 比较 (compare) and 照 is short for 对照 (contrast); together 比照 means "compare and contrast". This is an example of creating a new term from two other terms. Such kind of terms are not conversational usually. There are a part of the written language.

Answer (score 0):

“比照”，if we reference something firstly，then do something similar，we use “比照” to express our work is based on someone' work before. for example，“我比照着John cena的摔跤姿势练习摔跤”.

“比较” is similar to “compared with ...”.

we do not use “比照” to express the comparison action.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure, just use 比较. 比照is more literal and precise, so it is also less used